# Is there a better way to write a > b ? a : b

Tags: c#

I want to write

```
if (a /b > b/a) double foo = a/b;
else double foo = b/a;
```

This seems a very weird to write it, so I changed it to

```
double foo = a/b > b/a ? a/b : b/a;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: "better" is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: It depends on whether you need speed or not. The condition check and the ternary operator relate to speed because Math.Max is slower because of the method call that condumes CPU PROC CALL/RET and stack PUSH/POP.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Math.Max isn’t slower, because it will get inlined by the JITer (at least when compiled in release mode). There will be no CALL, no RET, and no PUSH/POP, just a CMP, JGE and MOV like when doing in “manually” with a ternary expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [Math.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=net-5.0).

```
double foo = Math.Max(a/b, b/a);
```

Answer (score 3):

A more readable way (IMHO, at least) would be to use the built-in [`Math.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=net-5.0):

```
double foo = Math.Max(a/b, b/a);
```